# How to use SIGUSR1 alternate values

Tags: c, linux, signals

In `man 7 signal` it shows that SIGUSR1 as `SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1`. If i use SIGUSR1 in my C code, i get the value 10. Is there any way to access the other values 30 & 16? Is it okay to use them explicitly in my signal handler like

```
if(signo == 16)
{
   printf("SIGUSR1 type 2 received\n");
}
```

Edit:In my code , there is a case statement that uses SIGUSR1 already. I need one more custom signal . I know there are RTSIGNALS and other options. But i wanted to know why they specify 16,30 in man page and never provide a way to use it.

Comment: You should always use `if(signo == SIGUSR1) { }` for sake of portability.

Comment: "i wanted to know why they specify 16,30 in man page" -- they say why; see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual says

> Several  signal  numbers  are  architecture dependent, as indicated in the "Value" column. (Where three values are given, the first one is usually valid for alpha and  sparc, the middle one for i386, ppc and sh, and the last one for mips. A - denotes that a signal is absent on the corresponding   architecture.)

The SIGUSR1 will have exactly one value on whatever machine you're running on ... there are no alternate values; just use the defined constant SIGUSR1. Using 16 will give you the wrong signal ... look further in the table and you will see SIGSTKFLT.

> I need one more custom signal

What's wrong with SIGUSR2?

Comment: Right.  On my machine `kill -l` displays the current values for the signals, and according to this, 30 is `SIGPWR` and 16 is `SIGSTKFLT` (so no SIGUSR1 there).

Comment: @Alfe "so no SIGUSR1 there" -- Seems unlikely. But kill -l is just printing some static string from the code ... it's not authoritative. That is, it knows the compile-time values of symbols like SIGUSR1, but it doesn't know which values are actually defined or available.

Comment: It's not authoritative but it is what is actually in use on the system.  The `kill` source code is matching the current system (and hopefully maintained with it).

Comment: "it is what is actually in use on the system" -- then you're misreading the output of kill -l ... it isn't possible that SIGUSR1 isn't defined on your system. If SIGPWR is 30 and SIGSTKFLT is 16, then most likely SIGUSR1 is 10. (Frankly, I have no idea what point Alfe, who isn't the OP, was trying to make. And hsr answer below is all wrong: a) the kernel generates signals other than SIGUSR[12] for specific reasons; sending them yourself for other reasons is a really bad idea. b) SIGKILL isn't the only signal handled specially. c) kill with random numbers gets EINVAL.)

Answer (score 2):

SIGUSR1 value is platform dependent.SIGUSR1 can be 30, 10, or 16. For example, x86-based Linux defines SIGUSR1 as 10. In fact, the only flavors of Linux that use 30 for SIGUSR1 are DEC Alpha and SPARC.

Comment: Also MacOS and *BSD use 30 for SIGUSR1.

Answer (score -1):

Signals are just numbers sent from one process to another.  Only in rare situations like `SIGKILL` the system interferes and handles them specially; the default is to send the signal number to the other process and let it handle this.  To wrap that up and make it portable, there are conventions which number is used for which situation (and a list of `#define`s supporting these conventions).  Some of these conventions are generalized in the POSIX standard which the `man 7 signal` is referring to.

You are totally free to use signals as you like (e. g. by using numbers without using any `#define`s).  Just be aware that by this you might lose portability and understandability.  (The next developer maintaining your code might want to kill you for this.)